# Running concurrent /parallel update statements (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing

I have a table that is basically records of items, with columns for each day of the month. So basically each row is ITEM , Day1, Day2, Day3, ....I have to run update statements that basically trawl through each row day by day with the current day information requiring some info from the previous day.

Basically, we have required daily quantities. Because the order goes out in boxes (which are a fixed size) and the calculated quantities are in pieces, the system has to calculate the next largest number of boxes.  Any "extra quantity" is carried over to the next day to reduce boxes.

For example, for ONE of those records in the table described earlier (the box size is 100)

[image: Box Calculation]

My current code is basically getting the record, calculate the requirements for that day, increment by one and repeat. I have to do this for each record. It's very inefficient especially since it's being run sequentially for each record.

- Is there anyway to parallel-ize this on SQL Server Standard? I'm thinking of something like a buffer where I will submit each row as a job and the system basically manages the resources and runs the query
- If the buffer idea is not feasible, is there anyway to 'chunk' these rows and run the chunks in parallel?

Comment: Maybe you should post the schema and query.

Comment: You could orchestrate parallel stored procedure execution using Service Broker.  However, RBAR processing in general should be avoided in favor of a set-based solution when possible.  If you can post example SQL of exactly what you are doing, maybe we can better help towards that end.

Comment: When you do this calculation, (roughly) how many days do you calculate and how many records? Is your SQL Server 2012 or newer?

Comment: The calculation is from the current date till the end of the month. Number of records ...a bit hard to judge but should be around 3000 on average. SQL Server is 2014, no worries there.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I played around with your data and was able to calculate the figures without row-by-row handling as such. I transposed the figures with unpivot and calculated the values using running total + lag, so this requires SQL Server 2012 or newer:

```
declare @BOX int = 100

; with C1 as (
  SELECT
    Day, Quantity
  FROM 
     (SELECT * from Table1 where Type = 'Quantity') T1
  UNPIVOT
     (Quantity FOR Day IN  (Day1, Day2, Day3, Day4)) AS up
),

C2 as (
  select Day, Quantity, 
  sum(ceiling(convert(numeric(5,2), Quantity) / @BOX) * @BOX - Quantity)
      over (order by Day asc) % @BOX as Extra
  from C1
),

C3 as (
  select 
    Day, Quantity, 
    Quantity - isnull(Lag(Extra) over (order by Day asc),0) as Required,
    Extra 
  from C2
)

select
  Day, Quantity, Required, 
  ceiling(convert(numeric(5,2), Required) / @BOX) as Boxes, Extra 
from C3
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d950/2)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this basically is what I'm doing for ONE of the rows. So I basically have to do this for EVERY ROW in the table - I have to cycle through each row and run this operation.....but it does give me a hint how to convert it into a batch set. Thanks!